# How to print subtotal in each page and grand total at the end of the page on Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, odoo-10, xlsxwriter

I have requirement to build invoice print out on excel using Odoo 10 as platform.

On this report we will need to have letter head, customer information, invoice no, and so on
then the detail of the invoice (products, qty, price, etc). But we need to print a sub total on every page (if total products are more than 1 page) and then grand total at the end of the page.

I'm using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) to write all the contents but i couldn't find any source on how we can indicate current row position is which page, is current page is end of page or not or how many rows can be printed in 1 page to be able to print sub total.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.